# unityのshader内で異なるサイズのtextureを合成

Tags: unity3d

unity5.6のshaderで質問があります。
2つのtextureを合成させたいのですが、合成元のサイズをはみ出すようなshaderの書き方が分かりません。
合成元のサイズで表示されて、はみ出した部分が描画されないのですが、うまく解決する方法は無いのでしょうか？

例えば、100x100pxで、中心点を変えて、最終出力が120x100pxになったりするとかです。
よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1):

Unity関係なく、シェーダー内ではテクスチャに解像度という概念はありません。
あくまで正規化された座標（UV座標、ST座標）のみが存在します。

よって、シェーダー内で2枚のテクスチャを合成したい場合は
それぞれの座標を事前に計算しておき、そこからブレンドすることになります。

コードとかないので、8割想像で回答しています。
見当違いでしたら申し訳ありません。

Comment: そうですよねー
unityのライブラリでその辺り吸収できる関数とかあれば・・・と思ってました